# How to interpret the definition of random variables in i.i.d random variables and law of large numbers?

Tags: random-variables, definition, law-of-large-numbers

I am learning stochastic process and I have a question about the definition of random variables:

As a brief non-rigorous definition, a random variable is a function mapping a sample space $\Omega$ to some real numbers and we may write it as $X(\omega),\omega\in \Omega$. Thus we may regard a random variable as a method of "numbering", right?

If it is so, how to interpret the independent and identically distributed random variables? I mean, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d, are they mapping the same sample space $\Omega$? Or they are mapping different sample spaces $\{\Omega_1,F_1, P_1\}$ and $\{\Omega_2,F_2, P_2\}$ respectively and just get the same distribution? It seems difficult for me to understand i.i.d from the "mapping" vision.

Moreover, I met similar problem when I learnt the law of large number (weak form). The definition of it  is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n}=\bar{X}_n$$

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|\bar{X}_n-E(\bar{X}_n)|<\epsilon)=1$$

I cannot understand the addtion of these random variables in this law. If a random variable is a mapping function, does it mean that if I add up many functions, I will get a function with constant outcome ($E(\bar{X}_n)$) ? I guess that someone may explain it to me from the view of "picking numbers" or "flipping coins", but these are not based on the actual definition of random variables, right? Random variables are just functions without any relationship with probability. The probability is just attached to the sample space. Would you please be so kind to help me from the "function" vision? Have I made any mistake in the above description ?

Comment: The sum (or any other operation) between two independent random variables produce another random variable on the product space of probability $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$, $F_1\times F_2$, $P_1\times P_2$

Comment: "identically distributed" means that they have the same distribution. In the continuous case it means that there is an isomorphism between the two measure spaces. When there are atoms there exists a "measure-preserving" map between the two, that is a map between standard spaces.... For more explanation see this
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44016/random-variables-with-same-distribution

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! In your first answer, you mentioned the product space of probability. However, I still cannot understand the law of large number. How can we add so many random variables (product of so many probability spaces?) to get a constant function? As for your second answer, I have to admit that my knowledge is not abundant enough to understand it (including content in your link). Would you please explain it more comprehensively?